# Bazel action output path

Tags: bazel

How do I get the absolute path that the sandbox worker will be executing in from skylark?

I've got a number of rules where I need to add an argument to the action command in skylark.  The argument is always the equivalent of "-fdebug-prefix-map=$(/bin/readlink -f .)=.".  I need the path so I can teach my tools to strip off the sandbox path and leave a relative path.  What's the best way to get access to that path?

Comment: Is there a case where readlink isn't giving the right result, or do you just want to know the bazel-y-est way of doing it?

Comment: I'd like to know the bazel-y-est way to do it.  I'm currently passing everything to bash -c so readlink expands correctly, but that results in some pretty ugly skylark.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use the `blaze-bin` symlink.

However, in general, you cannot (particularly if you use `--define`).

You should wrap your script in a blaze rule and use `blaze run`.